# Insert personalized info in iOS apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, qr-code

We are creating a **cordova app** for **ios** and **android** and we have everything ready, except one detail. The app will be downloaded from a **qr** code, and we need to insert in every app a different **phone number**, to relate the app with the place where it has been downloaded.

Is there a possibility to insert some code in the qr to pass it to the phone through the qr at the same time that we redirect to the Apple Store or iTunes?

Is there any other way maybe to achieve this goal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "insert in every app a different phone number, to relate the app with the place where it has been downloaded"? You can't do what you're attempting with the QR code since the app's not yet downloaded onto the device

Comment: You might not be able to get it into the app at the time of download, but you might be able to register that device by having it go to a unique URL and register the device and time on a server and the automatically forward the user to the App Store/Marketplace from there. Then, once the app is downloaded, add a custom number from when the device went to the original URL. I'm still not sure what information can be gleaned that way, but it sounds more promising than trying to do it through app distribution.

Comment: The idea is that every app is personalized for every client, and that it has to have its mobile number; depending from where you download it, you will have a diferent number; and we cannot make one app for business because will be hundreds of them.

Comment: I'll try your idea, @Fennelouski